# kafka topics not balanced after kafka brokers restart

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

We have strange behavior in our Kafka cluster

When we run the described info as

```
/usr/hdp/current/kafka-broker/bin/kafka-topics.sh –zookeeperzookeper_server:2181 –describe
```

We get for example ( this is the scenario on all topics )

We get on all topic (-1) and Isr is empty not as should be

```
Topic:__consumer_offsets           PartitionCount:50             ReplicationFactor:3               Configs:segment.bytes=1138822,cleanup.policy=compact,compression.type=producer
               Topic: __consumer_offsets          Partition: 0         Leader: -1           Replicas: 1000,1002,1001                Isr: 
               Topic: __consumer_offsets          Partition: 1         Leader: -1           Replicas: 1000,1002,1001                Isr: 
               Topic: __consumer_offsets          Partition: 2         Leader: -1           Replicas: 1000,1002,1001                Isr: 
               Topic: __consumer_offsets          Partition: 3         Leader: -1           Replicas: 1000,1002,1001                Isr: 
               Topic: __consumer_offsets          Partition: 4         Leader: -1           Replicas: 1000,1002,1001                Isr:

Topic:gen_topic_totCount:100    ReplicationFactor:3         Configs:
               Topic: gen_topic_tot: 0  Leader: -1           Replicas: 1002,1000,1001             Isr: 
               Topic: gen_topic_tot: 1  Leader: -1           Replicas: 1000,1001,1002             Isr: 
               Topic: gen_topic_tot: 2  Leader: -1           Replicas: 1001,1002,1000             Isr:
```

This happens after 2 days after we restart the zookeeper and kafka 
First all topics was balanced and Isr was with correctly brokers ids
But after more than 24 hours we get this state

From zookeeper logs we not saw something wrong and the same from server.log from kafka , and kafka brokers are up )

1000 , 1001 , 1002 - are the brokers ids

Comment: Wait you restarted zookeeper? What was the size of ensemble? FYI, it is recommended to have 3 nodes in an ensemble. If you want to take down one zookeeper node for whatever reason then 3 node ensemble can cater it.

Comment: we have 3 zookeeper servers , and 3 kafka servers

Comment: maybe 5 zookeepers server is better ?

Comment: If everything was okay after restart then I assume somehow connection to leader was disrupted.

Comment: so how we can verify any disconnected problem ?

Comment: Look into logs. You might find something. My suggestion would be to setup Prometheus and grafana. There is a kafka-exporter available for prometheus. This will help you monitor your kafka environment.